# Templated method interdependency

Tags: templates, compilation, dependencies

A few days ago I asked about regular class interdependency in C++, to which the response was the separation of method declaration and implementation into .cpp and .h filed to eliminate the implementation dependency.

The question now is how to deal with the same interdependency problem just with templated methods, which, as far as I know/read, cannot be strictly implemented (not accounting explicit implementation, which doesn't work in my case) separately between .h and .cpp files.

for example:

```
class Test_0
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    static void Testing_0()
    {
        Test_1::Testing_1();
    }
};

class Test_1
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    static void Testing_1()
    {
        Test_0::Testing_0();
    }
};
```

Is it possible to then separate the implementation for something like this so that it can actually compile?

Answer (score 0):

Usually we put the dependent codes into another class/function, and these two just call it.

but if you really need, there is also an ugly solution to do that:

```cpp
template<typename B>
class Test_0_{
    template<typename T>
    static void Testing_0(){
        B::Testing_1<T>();
    }
}
template<template<typename>class At>
class Test_1_{
    using A = At<Test_1_>;
    template<typename T>
    static void Testing_1(){
        A::Testing_0<T>();
    }
}
using Test_1 = Test_1_<Test_0_>;
using Test_0 = Test_0_<Test_1>;
```